# Linux Bonding with 2x10G LAN poor performance in kernels after 4.13.x

Tags: linux, performance, kernel, bonding

Here is our setup a DELL server with two 10G LAN ports and our old kernel 4.13.4 serving static video content using nginx (~8000 active connections) with the bandwidth of around 15.5G (1.2Mpps) on peak. We use Ubuntu lowlatency kernel built from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ without any changes to the default configuration (for the simplicity of this problem), which comes with the debian/ubuntu patches.
 
So we took the new kernel at the time 4.18.8 and we built it the same way we had done with the 4.13.x last year, but it was a **big fail**. The performance of the bonding was really poor, the network did not pass 10.5G at peak without being any more loaded than with the old kernel 4.13.4 - we collect system and network statistics every 10 seconds and the load and the IO are almost the same - no problem with IO of the disks, which are couple of SSDs. We tried to trace the problem - we tried 4.14.x (4.14.10 before the spectre and meltdown activation), 4.17.x and 4.18.x with and without spectre and meltdown activated (those we could turn off). Basically we have a better performance with almost ~10% of 4.17.x and 4.18.x without spectre and meltdown (those we could turn off) and almost the same speed with 4.14.10 (still not the same with 4.13). We've used the following line to turn off all we can of spectre and meltdown:

```
nospectre_v1 nospectre_v2 nospec_store_bypass_disable ssbd=force-off kvm-intel.vmentry_l1d_flush=never l1tf=off nopti no_rfi_flush kpti=off noibrs noibpb nospec no_stf_barrier
```

But **spectre_v1 and l1tf cannot be disabled**, even there are options for this. With the above line the network of kernel 4.14.70 is 20% better (than without it, but still way worse than it should be), but with kernel 4.18.12 (and 4.18.8) is almost the same poor performance.
During the tests of all kernels we did not change any other option in our server and we have an automation system, which checks for differences, so we are sure all custom option we change (in the system) are applied during boot. Our bonding configuration is:

```
bond-mode 4
bond-miimon 100
bond-lacp-rate slow
bond-slaves eth4 eth5
bond-xmit_hash_policy layer3+4
bond-downdelay 200
bond-updelay 200
```

Does anyone experience this behaviour and how we can proceed with further debugging? IS this spectre and meltdown performance degradation (really -50%??)? Could it be from a default option changed in kernels after 4.13 (though we checked the difference of the default configuration and between 4.14 and 4.13 and there is not so many changes there and we tried them). We also tried kernel 4.14.10 - just before spectre and meltdown code activation (probably the code is in the kernel, in fact) and still we could not reach the performance of the 4.13.x kernel though we manage to archive almost 90% of it.
We made a svg with FlameGraph of perf record:

```
perf record -F 99 -ag -- sleep 60
```

And kernels from 4.13.4 to 4.18.12 differs really in how many time the kernels are in function related to network stack. With the same traffic and load over the server the time kernel spends for function related to the network stack is significantly lower in 4.13.4 than in 4.18.12 and it's like gradual degradation over older to newer versions of the kernels.